# How could I read a small piece (a value) of a line in a data file in Fortran?

Tags: file, fortran, save, fragment, line

I've got the following problem:
There are "n" lines in a data file but it is not a problem because I am able to read a specific line which is interesting for me. However, I'm supposed to just read and save a fragment of this line (a value).
For example, the line is written in the file as:
`Resisting Moment = 2779.94 kN-m`.

Then, I have to read and save `2779.94`. Maybe, I can be able to do this by reading from "=" until the end of the line and after that, I should delete the last 5 characters. But, I do not know if it's possible or how to do this. Do anyone know?

The number of characters of the value may change (e.g., `Resisting Moment = 27790.945 kN-m`). Therefore, I am not able to pin a point to finish the read, I'm only able to pin the start point which there will not be changes (before the value).

Comment: What have you got so far ?  I (and I suspect others) am reluctant to teach you Fortran from square 1 but quite happy to help finish matters off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, somewhere in between @agentp and @Franz' solutions...

```
subroutine readrhs( line, val )
    implicit none
    character(*), intent(in)  :: line
    real,         intent(out) :: val
    integer :: n
    n = index( line, '=' )
    read( line( n+1 : ), * ) val
end

program  main
    implicit none
    character(100) :: line
    real :: val

    line = "resisting moment = 12312.9 kN-m"
    call readrhs( line, val )
    print *, "moment = ", val

    line = "force = 777.4 N"
    call readrhs( line, val )
    print *, "force = ", val
end
```

Answer (score 2):

To support your format, probably Fortran edit descriptors are
not enough and you need to write a parser specialized for
your case. If a typical file input is

```
resisting moment = 12312.9 kN-m
force = 777.4 N
```

a possible program which can read it is:

```
subroutine split_string(instring, string1, string2, delimiter)
    character(*), intent(inout) :: instring
    character(*), intent(in) :: delimiter
    character(*), intent(out):: string1, string2
    integer :: ind
    instring = trim(instring)
    ind      = scan(instring, delimiter)
    string1  = instring(1:ind-1)
    string2  = instring(ind+1:)
end subroutine split_string

real function parsed_read(file_unit)
    integer, intent(in) :: file_unit
    character(128) :: str, str1, str2, str3, str4
    read(file_unit,'(A)') str
    str  = trim(adjustl(str))
    call split_string(str, str1, str2, "=")
    str2 = trim(adjustl(str2))
    call split_string(str2, str3, str4, " ")
    str3 = trim(adjustl(str3))
    read(str3,'(F20.8)') parsed_read
endfunction parsed_read

program for
    real :: resisting_moment, force
    ! Read line by line and parse according to parsed_read function
    open(unit=1,file='inp.dat')
    resisting_moment = parsed_read(1)
    force            = parsed_read(1)
    close(1)
    print*,'resisting_moment:  ',resisting_moment
    print*,'force:  ',force
endprogram for
```

The function parsed_read splits lines by "=" and then by " "
and extracts the real value from the resulting string reading
from the string itself (in Fortran it is called internal file
in this context). The function needs to be adapted to
your specific format.

An alternative approach is employing Fortran namelists.
Fortran namelists allow to easily managing
I/O of parameters (e.g. https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/679582)
with many useful features already implemented.
After defining your variable as belonging to a namelist
you can read them (or a subset of them) with a single read instruction.
If your input file uses the namelist format, e.g.

```
&mynamelist
resisting_moment = 12312.9, ! kN-m
force = 777.4 ! N
/
```

a simple program reading it can be

```
program for
    real :: resisting_moment, force
    namelist /mynamelist/resisting_moment, force
    ! Read namelist
    open(unit=1,file='inp_nl.dat')
    read(1, mynamelist)
    close(1)
    print*,'resisting_moment:  ',resisting_moment
    print*,'force:  ',force
endprogram for
```

Answer (score 1):

```
character (len = 20), dimension (5) :: words
real::value
...
read(unit,*)words
read(words(4),*)value
```

take care not to try to read more "words" than there are on the line, eg for force (from @franz example) you should do

```
read(unit,*)words(:4)
```